# I upgraded my Azure virtual machine and it won't start

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I stopped my Azure virtual machine and upgraded it from 'Standard A1' to 'Basic A2' and now it won't start!

This is the error message I get: "The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request"

I've tried restarting 10 times in the past hour - same thing each time.  I just spent 2 days configuring this beast. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem - I raised a support ticket with Microsoft and they responded to say that this is a know problem when changing from Standard to Basic VMs.

They said their product team is working on a fix and expect it to be rolled out in the next 10 to 15 days.

In the meantime, they suggested deleting and redeploying the VM.  I would rather not do that, so will wait to see if their patch "fixes" my problem.

Comment: For anyone who does not know, if the downtime is acceptable, deleting and redeploying the VM does not destroy any data unless you explicitly choose to destroy the disks. I've definitely deleted VMs, retained the disks, then created new VMs pointing to the same disks in the past.

Comment: Thanks, I did this and all is okay now.  Apparently the cluster that the VM was on didn't support the basic VMs which caused the problem. MS are working to resolve this issue.